# Why python sting method (string.isupper) does not through error or warning without parenthesis (string.isupper()))

Tags: python

I tried to loop trough a word in python and check if a letter is upper case then excute some code,
the problem is the if statement executes it inner code even when the letter is lower and upper. And I want it to execute only when the letter is in Upper case.

```
word = raw_input("enter a word: ");
newword = ""
count = 0
for w in word:         
    if w.isupper: 
        print "checking";        
        newword += w.upper()
        count  += 1      
print newword
```

Comment: how is this relevant to VS?

Comment: Anyone with rep, please vote to close as this is off topic (typo). Don't just downvote the questions/answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parenthesis to your isupper call, like this:

```
w.isupper()
```

When you don't include the parenthesis, its just referencing the function pointer, which is not null or empty, and therefore the if statement resolves it as 'true'.

Comment: thank you guys, i just started learning python, and i have been debuging for 5 hours,

Answer (score 1):

You're missing parentheses in your call to `isupper()`, so you're trying to access the property isupper, which doesn't exist.

Check out the [str.isupper() Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) for usage.

To confirm, the fix is:

```
word = raw_input("enter a word: ");
newword = ""
count = 0
for letter in word:         
    if letter.isupper(): 
        print "checking";        
        newword += letter.upper()
        count  += 1      
print newword
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution